# How to pass a value to another ViewController by pushing in NavigationStack?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("History") as! History, animated: true)
        TV.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    }
}
```

I push to another ViewController(named History) and I want to pass my value which is in this ViewController to History ViewController.

I know we can pass value by using segue and  segue's destinationViewController and sourceViewController.

But there is no segue in this case.

So,I don't know how to assign a var's value to History's var.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let history = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("History") as! History
```

//Here U can Access the variable of History

```
history.yourVar=Assign Value

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(history, animated: true)

TV.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
```

Comment: Oh,no.What a foolish question I have asked.  Okay , thanks for the answer. It is very easy thing after reading your answer I think.